# Which JOIN type do I use to display NULL values in this query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join THREE tables.

The first table is **`transactions`** which contains details of "points" that students have earned. The relevant field here is `Recipient_ID` (the student receiving points).

The second table is **`purchases`** which contains details of "rewards" that students have purchased. The relevant fields here are `Student_ID` and `Reward_ID`.

The final table is **`rewards`** which details the rewards purchased. The relevant fields here are `Reward_ID`, `Cost_to_User` (the price the students pay for each reward; I'm currently not using this at all) and `Title`.

---

What I'm trying to do, provided with a specific list of student IDs, is display a list of students' points AND three most expensive reward purchases.

The SQL statement I've written thus far is:

```
SELECT
  t.Recipient_ID AS  `ID` ,
  SUM( t.Points ) AS  `Points Earned`,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.Title SEPARATOR ', '),', ',3 ) as `Rewards`
FROM  `transactions` t
JOIN `purchases` p ON t.Recipient_ID = p.Student_ID
JOIN `rewards` r ON p.Reward_ID = r.Reward_ID
WHERE  T.`Recipient_ID` 
  IN ( 90128, 90163, 34403, 35501 )
GROUP BY  t.`Recipient_ID`
```

This works to an extent - two students are displayed, with their point totals and latest rewards.

However, their point totals are vastly wrong, and I believe students aren't displaying if they haven't made any purchases.

**I would still like to display the students if they've made no purchases.**

---

I suspect it's my JOINs which are incorrect, but I also suspect `GROUP_CONCAT` isn't powerful enough to list the three most EXPENSIVE rewards. Do I need to change my JOINs, or do I need to use some sort of subquery?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should look at using a `LEFT JOIN` (See [Visual Explanation of Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)):

```
SELECT
  t.Recipient_ID AS  `ID` ,
  SUM( t.Points ) AS  `Points Earned`,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.Title SEPARATOR ', '),', ',3 ) as `Rewards`
FROM  `transactions` t
LEFT JOIN `purchases` p 
   ON t.Recipient_ID = p.Student_ID
LEFT JOIN `rewards` r 
  ON p.Reward_ID = r.Reward_ID
WHERE  T.`Recipient_ID` 
  IN ( 90128, 90163, 34403, 35501 )
GROUP BY  t.`Recipient_ID`
```

A `LEFT JOIN` will return all records from the `transactions` table even if there are no records in the `purchases` or `rewards` table.

Comment: Thanks for that bluefeet - the visual explanation in particular is incredibly useful. Do you have any idea why my `PointsEarned` may be wrong - and massively so?

Comment: Scrap that - you've answered the question, I'll take this to another one :)