# Why does my JOIN increase/possibly multiply the SUM in my query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to join THREE tables.

The first table is **`transactions`** which contains details of "points" that students have earned. The relevant field here is `Recipient_ID` (the student receiving points).

[image: transactions table]

The second table is **`purchases`** which contains details of "rewards" that students have purchased. The relevant fields here are `Student_ID` and `Reward_ID`.

[image: purchases table]

The final table is **`rewards`** which details the rewards purchased. The relevant fields here are `Reward_ID`, `Cost_to_User` (the price the students pay for each reward which is being used to order the `GROUP_CONCAT` function) and `Title`.

[image: rewards table]

---

The query I'm using is as follows:

```
SELECT
  t.Recipient_ID AS `ID` ,
  SUM( t.Points ) AS `Points Earned`,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.Title ORDER BY r.Cost_to_User DESC SEPARATOR ', '),', ',3 ) AS `Rewards`
FROM  `transactions` t
LEFT JOIN `purchases` p 
   ON t.Recipient_ID = p.Student_ID
LEFT JOIN `rewards` r 
  ON p.Reward_ID = r.Reward_ID
WHERE t.`Recipient_ID` 
  IN ( 90128, 90163, 33888, 34240, 137674 )
GROUP BY  t.`Recipient_ID`
```

---

**For some reason**, the `Points Earned` output is vastly wrong. **If I remove the `LEFT JOIN` on `purchases`, the `Points Earned` output is correct**.

What is it about that join that's sending my `SUM` command crazy?

---

**EDIT**: Please note that I require the `LEFT JOIN` commands as I'd like to display all students, including those that haven't made any purchases. Further details found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221133/which-join-type-do-i-use-to-display-null-values-in-this-query).

---

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting multiple records from the transaction table with the join.  You can use a subquery on the transaction table and it should fix this issue:

```
SELECT t.`ID` ,
  t.`Points Earned`,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.Title ORDER BY r.Cost_to_User DESC SEPARATOR ', '),', ',3 ) AS `Rewards`
FROM
(
  select t.Recipient_ID AS `ID`, sum(t.Points) AS `Points Earned`
  from `transactions` t
  group by t.Recipient_ID
) t
LEFT JOIN `purchases` p 
   ON t.`ID` = p.Student_ID
LEFT JOIN `rewards` r 
  ON p.Reward_ID = r.Reward_ID
WHERE t.`ID` 
  IN ( 90128, 90163, 33888, 34240, 137674 )
GROUP BY  t.`ID`
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1797a/7)

The strange total of the `points` is coming from the join of the tables. Since you are joining the tables on only the `Recipient_ID = Student_ID` if there are records in both tables you are getting a cartesian number of results.  So if you have 3 records for a student in the `transactions` table and 3 records in the `purchases` table the result will show 9 records for that student which alters the total.

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1797a/17)

Answer (score 0):

try with `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT
    t.Recipient_ID AS `ID` ,
    SUM( t.Points ) AS `Points Earned`,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.Title ORDER BY r.Cost_to_User DESC SEPARATOR ', '),', ',3 ) AS `Rewards`
FROM  `transactions` t
LEFT JOIN `purchases` p 
ON t.Recipient_ID = p.Student_ID
INNER JOIN `rewards` r 
ON p.Reward_ID = r.Reward_ID
WHERE t.`Recipient_ID` 
IN ( 90128, 90163, 33888, 34240, 137674 )
GROUP BY  t.`Recipient_ID`
```

Comment: Hi goodmood. Thanks for your efforts. The `INNER JOIN` makes no difference. I will also update my original post to include a link to one of my earlier questions as I require the `LEFT JOIN` to include students that haven't made any purchases.

Comment: then the rewards which will be inner join , updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for that - but the output remains the same, the `Points Earned` output is still incorrect I'm afraid.